# How to get org.mangosdk.spi.ProviderFor dependency for writing a custom Lombok transformation?

Tags: java, maven, lombok

I am writing a Lombok custom transformation, but I am stuck because Lombok handlers require using `org.mangosdk.spi.ProviderFor` annotation, and I can't find it in the Maven repositories. How are you supposed to get that dependency when making a custom Lombok transformation?

I tried looking at how that dependency is retrieved in https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok, but they just seem to have their own copy of the library in `lib` directory, which I think is a very inflexible way to manage your dependencies, so I wouldn't consider it for my own project.

So if I have a Maven project for a Lombok extension, how should I get that `org.mangosdk.spi.ProviderFor` class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lombok uses Ant+Ivy and not Maven. Lombok does not require the usage of the ProviderFor annotation. All that annotation does is automatically generate the META-INF/services file, which is past of the standard java set of APIs. You can also maintain such a file by hand.

For more information about the Service Provider Interface, you can also have a look at the [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/spi/wiki/GettingStarted) of the SPI project.

There is a [similar project](http://metainf-services.kohsuke.org/) that currently has better maven support.

NB. Since Google Code is going down soon, this project is in the process of being [migrated to Github](https://github.com/rspilker/spi)

Disclosure: I am a Lombok developer

Comment: Thank you for the great library. I already figured out myself how to make a custom transformation (would you check the pull requests on Github please?), but an explanation from a project developer is always valuable.

Comment: Thanks, @roel-spilker, are there any plans to migrate to Maven or Gradle?

Answer (score 1):

use the unofficial maven repository 'http://www.ebi.ac.uk/~maven/m2repo'