# Lombok import issue

Tags: java, lombok

I am trying to create my own lombok transformation by following current thread - [Create custom annotation for Lombok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41243018/create-custom-annotation-for-lombok)

I have imported lombok via maven but still cannot resolve a lot of dependencies such as: `JavacAnnotationHandler, ProviderFor` etc

Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.16.18</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: did you do the maven update? If you did check the jar is there or not

Comment: It is there, and all functionality works well for lombok. It is just then I am trying to develop custom transformation some classes are missing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing custom Lombok Annotation handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35550460/writing-custom-lombok-annotation-handlers)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [How to get org.mangosdk.spi.ProviderFor dependency for writing a custom Lombok transformation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30217603/how-to-get-org-mangosdk-spi-providerfor-dependency-for-writing-a-custom-lombok-t), you do not seem to need `ProviderFor` from the MangoSDK SPI.

There is an example project on GitHub ([hello-lombok](https://github.com/eldest/hello-lombok)) which uses it and the dependency `org.mangosdk.spi:spi:0.2.7-SNAPSHOT`, but that is all old software and is not the current approach to Lombok development.

Answer (score 0):

install direct from the jar in https://projectlombok.org/download

add the path to your exe of eclipse in IDE and install

in your eclipse.ini should have somthig like below

-javaagent:lombok.jar
-Xbootclasspath/a:lombok.jar

Comment: Installing the JAR from a download link instead of through maven sounds like a bad idea to me, but the hint with the `lombok.jar` in the `eclipse.ini` might do the trick.